# How to get the correct signature of PyQt methods

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, inspect

I'm trying to use the `inspect` module to determine the `Signature` of methods and I'm running into a problem with PyQt widgets. The widgets report a signature containing `*args` and `**kwargs`, but cannot be called with arbitrary keyword arguments:

```
>>> from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication
>>> from inspect import signature
>>> signature(QWidget.__init__)
<Signature (self, /, *args, **kwargs)>
>>> app = QApplication([])
>>> QWidget(c=10)
TypeError: 'c' is an unknown keyword argument
```

However, VSCode seems to be able to tell what the actual signature of the method is, as it correctly autofills calls or overrides:

```
QWidget(
```

shows the following tooltip:
[image]

and:

```
class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__
```

autocompletes the overriden `__init__` method to:

```
def __init__(self, parent: ,, flags: ,) -> None:
    super().__init__(parent=parent, flags=flags)
```

Is there a way I can actually get this correct signature of PyQt5's widget methods in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears the simplest soultion is to use the doc-string:

```
>>> QWidget.__doc__
'QWidget(parent: QWidget = None, flags: Union[Qt.WindowFlags, Qt.WindowType] = Qt.WindowFlags())'
>>>
>>> QWidget.windowTitle.__doc__
'windowTitle(self) -> str'
```

I'm not sure where VSCode gets its signature from. Some IDEs (like PyCharm) use [typehint stub files](https://pypi.org/project/PyQt5-stubs/) for code-completion and call-tips - but [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/python-language-server/issues/1854) seems to suggest VSCode may not do that (yet).

As for `inspect.signature`: the [note in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.signature) strongly suggests this won't always work with extension modules. It doesn't even work consistently with the python built-ins:

```
>>> inspect.signature(list)
<Signature (iterable=(), /)>   
>>>
>>> inspect.signature(dict)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/inspect.py", line 3130, in signature
    return Signature.from_callable(obj, follow_wrapped=follow_wrapped)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/inspect.py", line 2879, in from_callable
    return _signature_from_callable(obj, sigcls=cls,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/inspect.py", line 2410, in _signature_from_callable
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: no signature found for builtin type <class 'dict'>
```